# How to side load an image from a service

Tags: uploads, media

I am currently working on a WordPress plugin that creates dummy content.  I'd like to also have the plugin create random images using a service like http://lorempixel.com.  The problem however is that when accessing the service that an actual file name isn't generated.  You generate a random image like this:

http://lorempixel.com/1200/700/

How can I use the `media_handle_sideload()` function to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you already seen [`media_sideload_image()`](http://queryposts.com/function/media_sideload_image/) and [`wp_handle_sideload()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_handle_sideload/)?

Comment: I've seen them but I don't think it handles what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you don't.  Functions like sideload are for importing images into WordPress itself and using all the normal media library stuff. For images on an external service, use normal img tags.

If you want to copy an image from a URL, you sideload it. Not otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's exactly what I'm aiming to do though...

Comment: Is there a way to do this using curl?

Comment: can i use curl to grab the contents of the url and then create a temporary file on the server and THEN get that into the media library some how?

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I've solved this...

@otto - looks like all I had to do was use a bit of curl magic to do this...

code below as part of an advanced wordpress dummy page / post / image / text creator

```
function render_page() {
    if ($_POST['delete']) {
        $num_posts_deleted = 0;
        $num_images_deleted = 0;
        global $wpdb;

        $SQL = "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wpl_dummy'";
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results($SQL);

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $num_posts_deleted++;
            wp_delete_post( $row->post_id, true );
        }

        $SQL = "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wpl_dummy_image'";
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results($SQL);

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $num_images_deleted++;
            wp_delete_attachment( $row->post_id, true );
        }

    }
    if ($_POST['create']) {
        $num_posts_created = 0;
        // Build the options array
        $options = array();

        if ($_POST['number_of_paragraphs'])
            $options[] = $_POST['number_of_paragraphs'];

        if ($_POST['paragraph_length'])
            $options[] = $_POST['paragraph_length'];

        if ($_POST['decorate'])
            $options[] = 'decorate';

        if ($_POST['links'])
            $options[] = 'links';

        if ($_POST['ul'])
            $options[] = 'ul';

        if ($_POST['ol'])
            $options[] = 'ol';

        if ($_POST['dl'])
            $options[] = 'dl';

        if ($_POST['bq'])
            $options[] = 'bq';

        if ($_POST['code'])
            $options[] = 'code';

        if ($_POST['headers'])
            $options[] = 'headers';

        if ($_POST['ac'])
            $options[] = 'allcaps';

        if ($_POST['pr'])
            $options[] = 'prude';

        if ($_POST['fi'])
            $featured_image = 1;

        if ($_POST['fi_width'])
            $featured_image_width = $_POST['fi_width'];

        if ($_POST['fi_height'])
            $featured_image_height = $_POST['fi_height'];

        $options = implode('/', $options);


        // Match up
        $args = array(
            'public'=>true
        );
        $post_types = get_post_types( $args, 'objects', 'and' );


        if ( $featured_image )
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

        foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
            if ( $post_type->name != 'attachment') {
                if ( $_POST[$post_type->name]) {
                    for ($i=1; $i <= $_POST['number_of_posts_to_create']; $i++) {
                        // Get the random text
                        $curl = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                            CURLOPT_URL => 'http://loripsum.net/api/' . $options
                        ));
                        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
                        curl_close($curl);

                        // Massage our data
                        preg_match("/<h1 ?.*>(.*)<\/h1>/", $resp, $matches);
                        $title = $matches[1];
                        $body = str_replace($matches[0], '', $resp);

                        // Create the post
                        $post = array(
                            'post_content'  => $body,
                            'post_title'    => $title,
                            'post_type'     => $post_type->name,
                            'post_status'   => 'publish'
                        );  
                        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
                        update_post_meta($post_id, '_wpl_dummy', '1');


                        // Add and attach a featured image if necessary
                        if ( $featured_image ) {
                            $curl = curl_init();
                            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                                CURLOPT_URL => 'http://lorempixel.com/' . $featured_image_width . '/' . $featured_image_height . '/'
                            ));
                            $img_raw = curl_exec($curl);
                            curl_close($curl);

                            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

                            // place our file on the server in the appropriate directory
                            $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/wpl_' . time() . '_dummy.jpg';
                            file_put_contents ( $file , $img_raw );

                            // Check the type of tile. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
                            $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $file ), null );;

                            // Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
                            $attachment = array(
                                'guid'           => $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $file ), 
                                'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
                                'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $file ) ),
                                'post_content'   => '',
                                'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                            );

                            // Insert the attachment.
                            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );              

                            // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
                            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
                            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );


                            // Update the featured image
                            update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
                            update_post_meta($attach_id, '_wpl_dummy_image', '1');
                        }

                        $num_posts_created++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

}
        ?>

obviously more to it but this handles what I was aiming to accomplish.  Thanks for the nudge in the proper direction.

Comment: Please do _not_ just use plain `cURL` functions. There are `wp_remote_get()` and the rest of the WP HTTP API for that, which supports different remote request models, depending on what is installed. You will find some exhaustive answers on that topic. Also you _really_ could give `media_sideload_image()` a try :) ... and _sanitize & validate_ your `$_POST` data before pushing it to the DB. You know, getting hacked and such things ;)